# Can anyone help me to differentiate this equation?

Tags: derivatives

I need to differentiate this equation with respect to $x$:

$$
u(x)=\left[x\left((1-\alpha)+\alpha\left(\frac{\pi(\hat{W}/x-1)}{P}\right)^{\frac{\psi-1}{\psi}}\right)^{\frac{\psi}{\psi-1}}\right]^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}},$$

where
$\alpha\in(0,1)$, $x>0$, $\psi>0$, $\psi\neq 1$ and $\sigma>0$. $\pi,P,\hat{W}$ are positive constants.

Would be nice if the result can be expressed with a h-function. Let me rewrite the above as

$$u(x)=\left[x*h(x)\right]^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}}.$$

$$u'(x) = ?? h(x) ^{??} $$

Hope someone can help,
thanks in advance

-MB

Comment: Is $a$ the $\alpha$ above? Also, I assume $\psi \ne 1$, correct?

Comment: correct :) sorry my mistake

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: [Multiple logarithmic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation)?

Comment: yeah i looked at the chain rule quite carefull, but I find this eq hard :S. Now I wasted too many hours in my thesis on this, so I try here :)

Comment: Is $h$ differentiable?

Comment: Perhaps you might like to follow site rules and *show us what you have done*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
u = A^{\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma} \\
u'=\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma A^{-\frac 1\sigma} A' \\
A = xB^{\frac \psi{\psi-1}} \\
A'= B^{\frac \psi{\psi-1}}+\frac {x\psi}{\psi-1}B^{\frac 1{\psi-1}}B' \\
B = 1 - \alpha + \alpha C^{\frac {\psi-1}\psi} \\
B' = \alpha \frac{\psi-1}\psi C^{-\frac 1\psi} C' \\
C = \frac \pi P \left ( \frac W x - 1\right ) \\
C' = -\frac{ \pi W}{P x^2}
$$
Substitute everything back and you'll get $u'$

Comment: hey Kaster, thx for help

Comment: dont you need 1/(psi-1) in second term A' ?

Comment: @HansPede you're right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your second one follows the product and chain rules:$$\frac d{dx}u(x)=\frac d{dx}[x h(x)]^{\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma}=\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma[x h(x)]^{\frac{-1}\sigma}\frac d{dx}[x h(x)]\\=\frac{\sigma-1}\sigma[x h(x)]^{\frac{-1}\sigma}[x h'(x)+h(x)]$$

To get $h'(x)$ is more of the same, much more.

Comment: hi Ross, thank for help